# Text search for multiple value parameter in SQL Server with contains

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search

I have a multiple value parameter.

I want to perform the same thing as query 1 using full text search.

**Query 1:**

```
Declare @Class nvarchar(32)

select * 
from Products p
where p.Class in (@Class)
```

Now I want to use full text search, using contain:

**Query 2**

```
Declare @Class nvarchar(32)

select * 
from Products p
where contains(Class, @Class)
```

This query works fine if the user pick just one value for `@Class`.

If user picks more values it does not work.

Any idea how this can be achieved?

Comment: Depending on how many parameters you want to support you can use a sproc that accepts parameters and default them to null, or you can use a dynamic query which would support as many as you want but you need to use data validation in your application since dynamic sql allows for SQL injection.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `@Class` variable is comma delimited (ex: `one,two,three`), you can convert it to boolean syntax (ex: `'"one" OR "two" OR "three"'`) as follows:

```
declare @ClassBooleanStr nvarchar(max)
set @ClassBooleanStr = '"' + Replace(@Class, ',', '" OR "') + '"'

select * 
from Products p
where contains(Class, @ClassBooleanStr)
```

Comment: Very interesting solution. Actually I am creating a report in SSRS and my @Class parameter is defined in SSRS as a **Allow Multiple values**  parameter. Meaning it offers the user a list of all classes with check boxes.

Comment: Therefore @Class is not an actual comma delimited value

Comment: However I am going to try your solution, Maybe in background of SSRS  the multi select translated to comma delimited

Comment: Nope. It is not translated to comma delimited

Comment: @FatemehShakhsesalim According to a couple of sources I found online ([1](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2866/sql-server-reporting-services-using-multivalue-parameters/), [2](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/c02370b5-aeda-47ec-a3a8-43b2ec1e6c26/reporting-services-multi-value-parameter)) you can modify the report to make the parameter comma-delimited using `=JOIN(Parameters!Class.Value, ",")`, however I'm not sure where since I don't know SSRS that well.